# PHP-FPM cannot write to Nginx www folder

Tags: nginx, centos, php-fpm

Nginx is currently set to run as the user "nginx":

```
[root@localhost whmcs]# grep user /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user nginx;
```

PHP-FPM is set to run as the "nginx" user too:

```
[root@localhost whmcs]# grep '^user\|^group' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
user = nginx
group = nginx
```

They are definitely running as the "nginx" user:

```
[root@localhost whmcs]# ps aux | grep nginx | grep -v grep
nginx     55067  0.0  0.2 355128  9568 ?        S    15:54   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     55068  0.0  0.3 359488 13976 ?        S    15:54   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     55069  0.0  0.2 355128  9596 ?        S    15:54   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     55070  0.0  0.3 359508 13952 ?        S    15:54   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     55071  0.0  0.3 358712 13200 ?        S    15:54   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     55229  0.0  0.3 358456 12896 ?        S    15:54   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
root      62624  0.0  0.0  60572  1288 ?        Ss   16:15   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
nginx     62625  0.0  0.0  63096  2688 ?        S    16:15   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     62626  0.0  0.0  63096  2204 ?        S    16:15   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     62628  0.0  0.0  63096  2204 ?        S    16:15   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     62629  0.0  0.0  63096  2204 ?        S    16:15   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

PHP-FPM too:

```
[root@localhost whmcs]# ps aux | grep php-fpm | grep -v grep
root      55064  0.0  0.2 352152 11584 ?        Ss   15:54   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
nginx     55067  0.0  0.2 355128  9568 ?        S    15:54   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     55068  0.0  0.3 359488 13976 ?        S    15:54   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     55069  0.0  0.2 355128  9596 ?        S    15:54   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     55070  0.0  0.3 359508 13952 ?        S    15:54   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     55071  0.0  0.3 358712 13200 ?        S    15:54   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     55229  0.0  0.3 358456 12896 ?        S    15:54   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

My www folder for that domain is /var/www/whmcs and it's owned by "nginx":

```
[root@localhost www]# pwd
/var/www
[root@localhost www]# ls -lah | grep whmcs
drwxr-xr-x. 19 nginx nginx 4.0K Feb  7 16:15 whmcs
```

There doesn't seem to be anything relevant in /var/log/php-fpm/error.log or /var/log/nginx/error.log.

My installation for WHMCS on that domain still gives an error "Cannot write to web folder".

I have also disabled SELinux.

Can someone please give me some insight as to why this might be happening?

---

### ADDITIONAL INFO BELOW

EDIT: Peculiarly, it doesn't work even if I change the permissions for /var/www/whmcs recursively to 777.

EDIT 2: I gave shell login to the "nginx" user. It CAN create files in the /var/www/whmcs folder when logged in with it. Error on the page still the same though.

EDIT 3: Ownership and permission info requested by user @ezra-s:

```
[root@localhost var]# namei -mxo /var/www/whmcs
f: /var/www/whmcs
 Dr-xr-xr-x root  root  /
 drwxr-xr-x root  root  var
 drwxr-xr-x root  root  www
 drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx whmcs
```

EDIT 4: @Orphans, I don't seem to have /etc/php*/fpm/pool/conf.d/${CONFFILE}. This is all my /etc/php* files on CentOS 6.7:

```
[root@localhost etc]# find /etc/php*
/etc/php.d
/etc/php.d/curl.ini
/etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini
/etc/php.d/json.ini
/etc/php.d/phar.ini
/etc/php.d/zip.ini
/etc/php.d/pdo.ini
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini
/etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini
/etc/php.d/ioncube.ini
/etc/php.d/gd.ini
/etc/php-fpm.conf
/etc/php-fpm.d
/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
/etc/php.ini
```

Also here is the virtualhost file for the domain (I'm using a hosts file to access it):

```
[root@localhost etc]# cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/whmcs.com.conf 
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/whmcs;
    index index.php;

    server_name whmcs.com www.whmcs.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/whmcs;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is /var and /var/www readable by the nginx user?

Comment: Yes, both of them are with 755 permissions.

Comment: run this: "namei -mx /var/www/whmcs" show the output

Comment: @ezra-s I added the info you requested in the OP under EDIT 3. It all seems fine.

Comment: apologies, if you can add the "o" parameter to see the owners even better :)

Comment: check /etc/php*/fpm/pool/conf.d/${CONFFILE}
And also provide us with the virtualhost.

Comment: @ezra-s I edited the OP with the output of "namei -mxo".

Comment: @Orphans I added EDIT 4 to the OP for you.

Comment: Certainly it all looks good, if not SELinux or something of the likes, not sure what it may be, check php-fpm error logs and such to see, if none increase logging and see, worth checking /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf which is the actual pool working

Comment: What does /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf say?

Comment: @Orphans - here is a pastebin of the content http://pastebin.com/raw/hi8yWLT5 - It's all default, except for the user and group that I changed to "nginx".

Comment: Try define openbasedir

Comment: php_admin_value[open_basedir] = /PATH/TO/DOCUMENTROOT/:/tmp:/usr/bin

Comment: And I wonder why, noone has asked about any logs :P

Comment: I added php_admin_value[open_basedir] = /var/www/whmcs/:/tmp:/usr/bin to /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf. Restarted PHP-FPM - no errors, but the issue still occurs. Also, I mentioned in the OP that there's nothing relevant in the PHP-FPM/Nginx logs :(

Comment: Try to comment "listen.owner = nobody" and "listen.group = nobody", remove them from the pool and try again.

Comment: @Orphans, okay so in an act of desperation I moved the installation and www folder to /home/username/. Initially it didn't work but this time I could see an error for basedir in the PHP-FPM logs, so when I added that path to open_basedir, it started working. I'm still not sure why it didnt work for /var/www/ when the setup is identical there, but it works now. Thanks for your time mate, I appreciate it :)

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer also. :)

Comment: This is a web hosting control panel, and they make non-standard changes to the system, so we cannot know what is the reason for this behavior. You can expect more issues if you try to customize the setup.

Answer (score 7):

Check your selinux settings.  You might need to run:

```
$ sudo restorecon -R /var/www/whmcs
$ sudo setsebool -P httpd_unified 1
```

Reference: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/72271/469